# Бесконечный цикл прерывается в release билде

Tags: c++, циклы

Есть следующий код:

```
class A {
    public:
        void exec();

    private:
        std::list<std::vector<uint32_t>> valuesStores;
        std::mutex mutex;
        uint32_t currentBufferFullness = 0;

        static const int maxNumOfValues = 1000;
};

void A::exec() {
    std::cout << "start\n";
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        valuesStores.emplace_back(std::vector<uint32_t>());

        problemMethod();    //Метод, в котором возникает проблема

        if (valuesStores.back().size()) {

            mutex.lock();
            auto valuesIter = valuesStores.end();
            std::thread thread([this](auto valuesStoreIter) {

                    //Над valuesStoreIter производятся некие длительные операции
                    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                    std::cout << "We go to bed\n";
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
                    std::cout << "We wake up\n";

                    mutex.lock();
                    currentBufferFullness -= valuesStoreIter->size();
                    valuesStores.erase(valuesStoreIter);
                    mutex.unlock();

                }, --valuesIter);

            thread.detach();
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "end\n";
}

void A::problemMethod() {
    for (auto j = 0; j < (maxNumOfValues / 2); ++j) {
        while (maxNumOfValues <= currentBufferFullness) {   //Проблема возникает тут
        }

        valuesStores.emplace_back(rand() % 1000);
        mutex.lock();
        ++currentBufferFullness;
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Тут имеется некоторый метод `problemMethod`, выполняющийся в основном потоке, в котором осуществляется, считывание данных. По завершению выполнения метода, эти данные передаются в поток, в котором они будут как-либо обработаны, а пока идёт обработка, вновь вызывается метод `problemMethod` и считываются следующие данные. Когда значение некоего счётчика `currentBufferFullness` окажется больше или равно предельному значению, я ожидаю, когда какой нибудь из потоков освободит память из под переданных ему данных, после чего продолжаю считывание.

Данный алгоритм работает в debug билде (мною используется MinGW730_64), однако, при переключении в release, зацикливание завершается после пары первых итераций (между ними цикл не работает в холостую). Пока искал ошибку, предположил, что счётчик `currentBufferFullness` криво сбрасывается и цикл зацикливается окончательно, в итоге пришёл к следующему коду:

```
void A::problemMethod() {
    for (auto j = 0; j < (maxNumOfValues / 2); ++j) {
        while (true) {
            static auto justACrutchCounter = 0;
            if (UINT_MAX <= justACrutchCounter++) {
                std::cout << "";
            }
            if (maxNumOfValues > currentBufferFullness) {
                break;
            }
        }

        valuesStores.emplace_back(rand() % 1000);
        mutex.lock();
        ++currentBufferFullness;
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Потенциально пройти по положительной ветке, в которой должен быть выведен поток, возможно (хоть это и не так) и теперь цикл имеется постоянную нагрузку, не позволяющую скипнуть его работу.

Благодаря такому костылю цикл не прерывается, что хорошо, но выглядит это ещё хуже, чем было до него, да и хотелось бы разобраться, с чем связана такая работа цикла в release билде и что с этим делать.

Comment: Не надо описывать недостающий код, приводите его в вопросе чтобы читающие могли воспроизвести такое поведение. А проблема, очевидно, связана с многопоточностью и находится в коде который вы не привели. Тут даже не понятно, что такое `mCurrentBufferFullness`. Зато понятно, что ждать других потоков крутясь в цикле - это однозначный фейл.

Comment: @VTT постарался привести недостающий код, убрав совсем лишнее. Полагаю у Вас по нему будет много замечаний, буду рад выслушать. Касательно ожидания других потоков, я согласен, цикл выглядит достаточно коряво, возможно Вы предложите вариант лучше, о котором я не знаю/не подумал.

Comment: @VTT Касательно проблемы в многопоточности - судя по увиденному мной, алгоритм производит 2 итерации чтения файла, отправляет эти данные на обработку и запись во временные файлы, и пока идёт обработка, основной поток крутится в цикле. Т.к. запись занимает относительно длительное время, в цикле поток крутится довольно долго и дальше с ним что-то происходит. Попытка установить что же с ним происходит привела меня к последнему фрагменту кода, с которым цикл, внезапно, начал работать корректно, что привело меня к мысли о том, что срабатывает какой-то механизм защиты от зацикливания,

Comment: но видя нагрузку в лице попытки вывести некий поток, защита не срабатывает. Таким образом, думается мне, что проблема не совсем в многопоточности.

Comment: Ознакомтесь с [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ну а вообще похоже что доступ к `mCurrentBufferFullness` из разных потоков не синхронизирован

Comment: @VTT `mCurrentBufferFullness` при инкременте в `readValuesFromFile` обёрнут в тот же мьютекс, что и в прочих потоках, просто сокращая код случайно затёр, моя вина. Сейчас попробую набросать нормальный пример, опять же, моя вина.

Comment: @VTT я переписал пример, если Вас не затрудник, не могли бы взглянуть? Проверил, проблема продолжает воспроизводиться. Также, в первом комментарии, Вы говорили, что ожидание потоков крутясь в цикле это фейл, мне бы хотелось услышать Ваше мнение, чем и как его можно заменить в данном случае.

Comment: "доступ к mCurrentBufferFullness из разных потоков не синхронизирован"

Comment: @VTT Вы оказались правы, опять. Обернул `mCurrentBufferFullness` в `std::atomic` и всё заработало. Большое спасибо за Вашу помощь. Однако не совсем понял следующее - `mCurrentBufferFullness` был обёрнут в мьютексы везде, за исключением сравнения `while (maxNumOfValues <= currentBufferFullness)`, я полагал, что в худшем случае, будет взято старое значение счётчика и будет выполнена лишняя итерация (или парочка) в цикле, что сейчас для меня не критично, и на одной из последующих итераций будет взято обновлённое значение. Как это отрабатывает в действительности?

Comment: Это сложный вопрос. С одной стороны, обращение к переменной без синхронизации само по себе является неопределенным поведением. С другой стороны, бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов компилятор имеет право игнорировать. А вообще вместо этого цикла следовало бы использовать [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: @VTT А вот о том, что цикл игнорировался всё это время, я и не подумал, полагал что несколько первых итераций стабильно проходят. Вопрос может и сложный, но такого ответа, на текущем этапе, мне более чем хватит. Ещё раз спасибо за помощь, за замену цикла, и за терпение, буду разбираться.